# Duplicate Association Path Error in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I've run into an issue when I try to programmatically build a Criteria object based on a user's search criteria. Simply put, the user can enter one or more search criteria and, based on what they enter, I build a Criteria object, execute a query based on it, and display the results. Unfortunately, when I use certain search criteria together, I'm getting this error:

duplicate association path: assignments

In my database, I have a table that contains issues (called Issue). An issue can have multiple people assigned to it, in different roles (for example, it might have an Auditor and a QA Specialist assigned to it). Assignments are maintained in a separate table called Assignment. The tables look something like this:

```
+-------------+    +-----------------+
| Issue       |    | Assignment      |
+-------------+    +-----------------+
| issueID     |    | assignmentID    |
+-------------+    | issueID         |
                   | assigneeID      |
                   | isActive        |
                   | reviewType      |
                   +-----------------+
```

The column issueID is a primary key in Issue and a foreign key in Assignment.

In my Java code, I have something like this:

```
public List<MortalityCase> searchCases(SearchCriteria criteria)
{
    Criteria search = HibernateUtil.getSession().createCriteria(Issue.class);

    if ( criteria.getIssueNumber() != null )
    {
        search.add(Restrictions.eq("issueNumber", criteria.getIssueNumber()));
    }

    ...

    if ( criteria.getAuditor() != null )
    {
        search.createCriteria("assignments")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("assignee", criteria.getAuditor()))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("isActive", "Y"))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("reviewType", getReviewType(TypeOfReview.AUDITOR)));
    }
    if ( criteria.getQASpecialist() != null )
    {
        search.createCriteria("assignments")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("assignee", criteria.getQASpecialist()))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("isActive", "Y"))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("reviewType", getReviewType(TypeOfReview.QA_SPECIALIST)));
    }

    ...

    return search.list();
}
```

This works fine if the user searches for issues assigned to either an Auditor OR a QA Specialist. However, if the user tries to search for an issue assigned to both a given Auditor AND a given QA Specialist, I get the error mentioned above.

I found [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=931249) on the Hibernate forums which was started 7 years ago and points out that this is a limitation on Hibernate. I was hoping that something would have been done about this since then, but the thread has actually remained "alive" until June of 2010 with no response/fix mentioned.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0):

If both `getAuditor()` and `getQASpecialist()` are non-null, then isn't what you really want is to do a query where the `assignee` value is equal to `criteria.getAuditor()` OR `criteria.getQASpecialist()`?

for example:

```
if ( criteria.getAuditor() != null && criteria.getQASpecialist() != null) {
     search.createCriteria("assignments")
        .add(Restrictions.or(
             Restrictions.eq("assignee", criteria.getAuditor()),
             Restrictions.eq("assignee", criteria.getQASpecialist())
         )
       ....
}
```